# R - Removing rows from one table based on unique combination from another table

Tags: r

I have two tables.
Table A - Base table with full data.
Table B - Contains grouped data by the combination (Origin- Destination- Carrier- Class). It has only those combinations which have both Premium and Economy class and also greater than 100 passengers each.

My objective is to only include those rows in Table A which pertain to combinations in Table B.
Sample tables are below -

Table A

| ItinID | Origin | Destination | Carrier | Class | Fare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB | BC | Delta | Econ | 100 |
| 2 | AB | BC | Delta | Premium | 500 |
| 3 | CD | DE | American | Econ | 200 |
| 4 | EF | FG | United | Econ | 200 |
| 5 | AB | BC | Delta | Econ | 150 |
| 6 | AB | BC | Delta | Premium | 700 |

Table B

| Origin | Destination | Carrier | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | BC | Delta | Econ |
| AB | BC | Delta | Premium |

The output table that I need is-

| ItinID | Origin | Destination | Carrier | Class | Fare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB | BC | Delta | Econ | 100 |
| 2 | AB | BC | Delta | Premium | 500 |
| 5 | AB | BC | Delta | Econ | 150 |
| 6 | AB | BC | Delta | Premium | 700 |

Also, is there a way to skip making Table B altogether and directly running operation on Table A to get the output table?

Thank you

Comment: There are different ways to fullfill the task. If you want to do the task more often, i suggest writing a function. with dplyr commands in it and variables that you can put in like:  Myfunc <- function(Input_table_B){ #data filtering }. It is also possible to put in the different parameters like Myfunc <- function( c(Origin), c(Destination). ...) { #data filtering}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Here are base, dplyr and sqldf solutions.  We join A and B and then sort by ItinID (although it seems that the dplyr solution is already sorted that way so we omit that part for it).

```
m <- merge(A, B)
m[order(m$ItinID), names(A)]
##   ItinID Origin Destination Carrier   Class Fare
## 1      1     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  100
## 3      2     AB          BC   Delta Premium  500
## 2      5     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  150
## 4      6     AB          BC   Delta Premium  700

library(dplyr)
semi_join(A, B)
## Joining, by = c("Origin", "Destination", "Carrier", "Class")
##    ItinID Origin Destination Carrier   Class Fare
##  1      1     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  100
##  2      2     AB          BC   Delta Premium  500
##  3      5     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  150
##  4      6     AB          BC   Delta Premium  700

library(sqldf)   
sqldf("select A.* from B natural join A order by ItinID")
##   ItinID Origin Destination Carrier   Class Fare
## 1      1     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  100
## 2      2     AB          BC   Delta Premium  500
## 3      5     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  150
## 4      6     AB          BC   Delta Premium  700
```

**2)** Without B we can use `by` and `subset` from base or dplyr's `filter` or  correlated subqueries in sql.

```
do.call("rbind", by(A, A[c("Origin", "Destination", "Carrier")], subset, 
  all(c("Econ", "Premium") %in% Class) & all(Fare >= 100)))
##   ItinID Origin Destination Carrier   Class Fare
## 1      1     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  100
## 2      2     AB          BC   Delta Premium  500
## 5      5     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  150
## 6      6     AB          BC   Delta Premium  700

library(dplyr)
A %>%
  group_by(Origin, Destination, Carrier) %>%
  filter(all(c("Econ", "Premium") %in% Class) & all(Fare >= 100)) %>%
  ungroup
## # A tibble: 4 x 6
##   ItinID Origin Destination Carrier Class    Fare
##   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <chr>   <chr>   <int>
## 1 1      AB     BC          Delta   Econ      100
## 2 2      AB     BC          Delta   Premium   500
## 3 5      AB     BC          Delta   Econ      150
## 4 6      AB     BC          Delta   Premium   700

library(sqldf)
cond <- "x.Origin = y.Origin and x.Destination = y.Destination and
  x.Carrier = y.Carrier"
fn$sqldf("select * from A x where 
    'Econ' in (select Class from A y where $cond) and 
    'Premium' in (select Class from A y where $cond) and
    100 <= (select min(Fare) from A y where $cond)")
##   ItinID Origin Destination Carrier   Class Fare
## 1      1     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  100
## 2      2     AB          BC   Delta Premium  500
## 3      5     AB          BC   Delta    Econ  150
## 4      6     AB          BC   Delta Premium  700
```